# spring jackson Map Deserialization

Tags: java, spring, jackson, deserialization

I'm passing via a Spring controller a json object that looks like this:

```
{
  "dataset":"myDataset",
  "typeProperties":[
    "myProperty"
  ],
  "stopWords":{
    "de":[ "daß","allem","dem"],
    "fr":["salut"]
  }
}
```

The corresponding java object is:

```
public class DatasetConfigRequest {
    String dataset = "";
    List<String> typeProperties;
    HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> stopWords = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();

//getter and setters
```

But when  I pass it I get the following error:

```
JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.HashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.HashMap<java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object>` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 104] (through reference chain: eu.qanswer.core2.server.controller.payload.dataset.DatasetConfigRequest["stopWords"])]
```

I understand that the problem is the HashMap with values a ArrayList. But how to solve this?

Thank you
D063520

Comment: Is more clear to create a class to hold the `stopWords` values as @M.Çıklabakkal said, thus you have more control about what is coming from the client.

Answer (score 0):

Create new class and name it stopWords add id and list fields and finally add a field to dataset class name it stopWords

Comment: Hi! If I make a new class as you said then the id="de" and list=["daß","allem","dem"]. But then where to put "fr". Do you mean I should put a list of stopWords class in the DatasetConfigRequest class?

Comment: You should define "stopWords" as a array in  the dataset class, than you can add multi stopwords object.